# How do you interpret null coefficients in a fixed effects regression?

Tags: regression, econometrics, fixed-effects-model

I'm trying to understand how the Covid vaccination status is affected by vaccination camps run by the factories (units) that employ them. My independent variables is the number of vaccination camps run by each factory, for a week 't'. My dependent variable is vaccination status dummy (vaccinated or not vaccinated, where vaccinated is defined as having ATLEAST 1 dose) and it's leads.

I ran a fixed effects regression with time, unit and employee fixed effects and got some very weird results[![enter image description here[image] Essentially, my coefficients are 0 when i include employee fixed effects but not when I am adding unit level fixed effects instead...

Can this be explained via collinearity or is there something wrong with the way I have coded my dummy?

Comment: What are the “units” here? Factories?

Comment: Yes units are factories!